Third party rest API call using oAuth 2.0 from Azure synapse web activity
I have a task where I need to connect to external URL from Azure synapse and get few data. We were doing that using synapse web activity and using basic authentication. Now the provider has asked us to use oAuth 2.0 and has provided details about Authenticating URL with client ID and secret.
Now my question is in synapse web activity there is no option to select for 0Auth 2.0 but with little searching I realized that I need to use synapse web activity and get bearer token and then pass this token as header to other tasks. The problem is I am not able to get bearer token from when trying from synapse. I am able to get the token if I am using postman. Can anyone please guide me what options should i select in web activity. I am doing as below. Below is just a test to get the token.

the setting for token are as below.
The URL is the one which will provide the token. In body I have added client ID and secret

But when I debug I get error
{     "errorCode": "2108",     "message": "{\"error\":\"access_denied\",\"error_description\":
  \"Unauthorized\"}",     "failureType": "UserError",     "target": "Token",     "details": [] }


You need to use the below configurations in the web activity to achieve your requirement.
URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token

Body : grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<your_client_id>&client_secret=<your_client_secret>&resource=https://management.azure.com

Headers : Content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded


Bearer token in the output:

To store this in a string variable, you can use below expression.
@activity('Web1').output.access_token


Thanks for the answer I was trying the same method. But you missed in my question that the token URL is not from MS but from third party. Where instead of resource i have audience that needs to be added. I finally figured it out and will post the answer the trick is the request body for me was incorrect. Plus the use of 'Accept Application/Json' parameter in header would ruin your token. At least in my case.

Good to know that your issue got resolved. I have not used any 3rd party rest api so that's why I have given a generalized solution. If you have a solution, you can post it as an answer and accept it, which can benefit the community who are facing the same issue.

@Shanky you mentioned that you figured out the issue and that you will post the answer. Do you have a link to the solution, or would you be willing to post it here?
